# If $f$ has a primitive on $\Omega$, then $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ has a primitive on $\Omega$, then $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$

I don't understand the proof of the corollary $2.2.12$ [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/CV/CV2.pdf#page=14). How can one apply corollary $2.2.11$, if it holds only for analytic functions, that's what we want to show , or not ?

[image]

Comment: Can you include the corollaries here? That would make the question self-contained. If you don't and the link dies, the question breaks.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer OK i'll edit

Comment: If I guess correctly what corollary 2.2.11 is, we apply it to the primitive, not to $f$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yes but the  formula holds for analytic $f$

Comment: Does that text make a difference between "analytic" and "holomorphic"?

Comment: I meant "does the text make a _systematic_ difference". One often defines a function as holomorphic on an open set $U$ if it is complex differentiable on $U$, and a function is analytic if it can be represented as a power series around each point of its domain. Then it's a theorem that a function is analytic if and only if it is holomorphic. Other authors just use the terms interchangeably from the beginning. Whether that distinction is made influences the (length of the) answer.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Ok I think I understand what you mean, so in this case the primitive of $f$ is differentiable, hence holomorphic, but this is equivalent to being analytic, and so $f$ is also analytic, sorry for the inconvenience, but I was also not sure that the author switched analytic with holomorphic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ has a primitive $F$, then $F$ is analytic. Namely, $F'=f$. But this implies that $F$ has derivatives of all orders, and hence, $f$. In fact, $f'=F''$, $f''=F'''$, etc.